# Multivariable Equation: $4ab=5(a+b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all Natural roots of the following multi-variable equation :
$4ab=5(a+b)$

I have tried many handy candidate solutions and it seems there is no SOLUTION!
Indeed we should show that it has no root set in Natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 4ab-5a-5b=0  $$
$$ 16ab - 20a - 20 b = 0  $$
$$ 16ab - 20 a - 20 b + 25 = 25  $$
$$ (4a-5)(4b-5) = 25  $$
three positive divisors , the possible values $(4a-5,4b-5)$ are
$$  (-1,-25) \Longrightarrow a=1, b=-5$$
$$  (-5,-5) \Longrightarrow a=0, b=0$$
$$  (-25,-1) \Longrightarrow a=-5, b=1$$
$$  (1,25) \Longrightarrow a=3/2, b=15/2$$
$$  (5,5) \Longrightarrow a=5/2, b=5/2$$
$$  (25,1) \Longrightarrow a=15/2, b=3/2$$
so the original $a,b$ are integers just the first three times.

Comment: Excellent Solution!!! and it's easily seen that there is no solution in Natural numbers because we must have: 4a-5=1 or 5 or 25

Answer (score 2):

Well, $a=0=b$ works, but let's exclude them.  Rearrange to get $$\frac45=\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac 1a + \frac 1b$$

If both a and b are greater than 2 than the right hand is less than or equal to $\frac 23$ so that's out.  Hence one of them, let's say a, is 2 (clearly, neither can be 1).  But it is easy to see that $a=2$ does not lead to a solution in the natural numbers so there are none.

Comment: Unfortunately your reasoning has some mistakes: if a>2 and b>2 then we have 1/a<1/2 and 1/b<1/2 so 1/a + 1/b < 1

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi The inequality $a > 2$ is equivalent to $a \geq 3$ for natural numbers $a$. There's nothing wrong with the bound of $2/3$.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi My argument relied on the fact that a and b are integers, as specified by the problem.  Thus, as pjs36 points out, saying that they are bigger than 2 implies they are at least 3.

Comment: Yes you both are right,I do understand.Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\dfrac{5b}{4b-5}=a$ which must be an integer

$\implies(4b-5)$ must divide $5b$

Clearly, $b=0$ is a solution

If integer $d\ne0$ divides both $4b-5,5b;d$ must divide $4(5b)-5(4b-5)=25$

$\implies d=\pm1,\pm5,\pm25$

So, $4b-5$ must be one of $\{\pm1,\pm5,\pm25\}$

Comment: Thank you dear, your method is also quite interesting!