# Integer solutions to $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{12}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{12}$$

I'm trying to find all integer solutions to this equation. I've played with this equation algebraically to see if I can figure out the restrictions on $a$ and $b$. For example, I know at least one of them must be divisible by $12$ because

$$   a + b = \frac{ab}{12}  $$

I'm wondering if there are more general approaches.

Comment: It's `\frac`, not `/frac`.

Comment: Can you constrain $a$ and $b$ to be positive?

Comment: The fact that 12 divides ab does not show that it divides either a or b, as 12 divides 3*4 for example.  Indeed taking $a=3$ and $b = -4$ gives a solution to your equation.

Comment: Yikes. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375041/multivariable-equation-4ab-5ab

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that 
$$\frac 1a + \frac 1b = \frac 1{12} \implies \frac{a+b}{ab} = \frac{1}{12} \implies 12a + 12b = ab \implies ab - 12a - 12b + 144 = 144 \\
\implies (a - 12)(b-12) = 144.$$
Adding by 144 is a trick for making the LHS factorable. Since that $ab -12a = a(b - 12)$, we would have to add $144$ to $-12b$ in order to make another $b-12$ term.

Now, we do casework on the factors of 144. There should be $\tau(144) = \tau(2^4\cdot 3^2) = 5\cdot 3 = 15$ factors of 144 so 30 total solutions including negative factors.

**Edit**: I'll write out every solution to this.
\begin{align*}
144 = 144 \cdot 1 &\implies (a,b) = (156, 13) \\
144 = 72 \cdot 2 &\implies (a,b) = (84, 14) \\
144 = 48 \cdot 3 &\implies (a,b) = (60, 15) \\
144 = 36 \cdot 4 &\implies (a,b) = (48, 16) \\
144 = 24 \cdot 6 &\implies (a,b) = (36, 18) \\
144 = 18 \cdot 8 &\implies (a,b) = (30, 20) \\
144 = 16 \cdot 9 &\implies (a,b) = (28, 21) \\
144 = 12 \cdot 12 &\implies (a,b) = (24,24)
\end{align*}
and its reverse. 
For negative solutions, we have
\begin{align*}
144 = -144 \cdot -1 &\implies (a,b) = (-132, 11) \\
144 = -72 \cdot -2 &\implies (a,b) = (-60, 10) \\
144 = -48 \cdot -3 &\implies (a,b) = (-36, 9) \\
144 = -36 \cdot -4 &\implies (a,b) = (-24, 8) \\
144 = -24 \cdot -6 &\implies (a,b) = (-12, 6) \\
144 = -18 \cdot -8 &\implies (a,b)= (-6, 4) \\
144 = -16 \cdot -9 &\implies (a,b) = (-4, 3)  
\end{align*}
and its reverse. There is a total of 29 solutions since $-12 \cdot -12$ gives (a,b) = (0,0).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want positive integer solutions and that $a\leq b$

Both $a$ and $b$ need to be at least $13$.

Let $a=13$ and solve for $b$ to see if it is an integer (it's $156$).

Move on to $a=14$, and so on. As you increase $a$, $b$ decreases. So this won't go on for too long. What would it take for $a=b$? If they were equal $a=b=24$. So you only need to do this for $a=14\ldots24$.

Also your deduction about divisibility by $12$ is not correct. Maybe one is divisible by $4$ and the other by $3$. Etc.

---

If you allow one of them to be negative, say $a$, that means $b>\frac{1}{12}$, so $b<12$. This means you only have $b=1\ldots11$ to examine, and solve for $a$ in each case to see if it is an integer.

And clearly they can't both be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a and b to both be positive, I'd go by brute force: We note that we can't have both a, b > 24 (as the sum of the reciprocals would be too small).  Conversely, neither can be < 13.  Thus the smaller of them, let's say a, must be between 13 and 24 (inclusive).  Easy to check each case.

If you want to allow for negative values as well, the same argument shows that we can't have both |a| and |b| > 24, though the lower bound doesn't hold any longer.  Still easy to check all the cases.